# perror shows Not Enough Memory - How to debug?

Tags: c, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

When my function is called for 5th or 6th time during runtime. 
I start getting this "Not enough memory" error from `perror();`

How can I debug/troubleshoot where the problem is? 
where can I see total memory usage of my program during runtime or the maximum memory usage allowed during runtime?

Is there any way to handle such errors during runtime and re-load the program or free up whole memory used by the program?

I am using the Turbo C Compiler.

EDIT:
No dynamic memory allocation is being used.

EDIT:
If a call to a function is made from main() and then that function calls another function and again that function calls a different function, kinda like  a loop. Could this cause memory issues? All of this functions are of return-type void.

Comment: You might want to show us the code that causes the problem.

Comment: @Bart I have added the code where the perror() is used and the error occurs.

Comment: What happens if you move your `perror()` call before the calls to `cleardevice()` and `gotoxy()` ?

Comment: @AnilDewani: then there must be some other piece of code elsewhere allocating memory. Some other `fopen()` without `fclose()`?

Comment: Had already checked for those before. Nope, all fopen's are fclose'd.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stack overflow.

Happened due to nested functions.
Traced the bug using stackavail() function from malloc.h